# If tomatoes are fruit

Tags: tomatoes, condiments, ketchup

isn't ketchup (catsup) technically a smoothie?

Comment: You don't typically cook smoothies, where as ketchup is cooked down quite a bit.

Comment: Okay, the question is a little silly, and wrong, but does it really deserve four down votes?  I mean, really?

Comment: @Daniel: I would hazard a guess that some people view at as a [joke question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/joke-questions-please-refrain/) or at least borderline, hence the downvotes.  I've always believed that the best way to handle them is to just answer them honestly and not take the (flame)bait - but at the same time that doesn't mean we should encourage it.  Maybe the question is actually not a joke, but that is one reason why it helps to be specific and detailed, to avoid negative interpretations.

Comment: It was borderline joke/actual question. I honestly did not know what constituted as a smoothie, and ketchup is smooth... I guess... Mostly it was intended to be a little humorous, and as such I expected this type of response. I am grateful for the serious answers.

Comment: I'm upvoting, not because I think it is the greatest question we've ever had, but I think @Aaaronut's answer shows that it is well posed and valid, so I don't think it deserves the down votes.

Comment: Downvote for just copying an (old) meme into a question: http://memegenerator.net/Philosoraptor/ImageMacro/3260626/If-tomatoes-are-a-fruit-isnt-ketchup-technically-a-smoothie

Comment: Upvote for humor, and a good answer from @Aaronut

Comment: If the word fruit is used in a way to include tomatoes then it should also include peppers, squashes, aubergines, cucumbers etc. Why do tomatoes get all the attention?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Definition 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothie):

> A smoothie (also known as a "smoothy") is a blended, chilled, sometimes sweetened beverage made from fresh fruit (fruit smoothie) or vegetables and in special cases can contain chocolate.

[Definition 2](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/smoothie):

> [...] a thick beverage of fruit pureed in a blender with ice and milk, yogurt, or juice.

1. Ketchup is not considered a beverage by anybody I know.
2. Ketchup is not made only from fresh fruit and ice/milk/yogurt/juice.  It has many other ingredients.
3. Ketchup is probably not made in a blender.
4. There are plenty of food items made from fruit that aren't smoothies (is applesauce a "smoothie?").

So, no, it's not a smoothie simply because it contains a fruit.

Comment: I know a two year old that would dispute point (1), but overall, good answer!

Comment: @Michael: I'm not quite as far gone as that two year old, but I do consider french fries to be utensils!

Answer (score 3):

During the Reagan years, it (ketchup) was allowed to be a vegetable option for school lunches, e.g. if you had french fries and ketchup, that counted as two vegetables.

Comment: Wasn't Reagan, it was one of the Bushes.

Comment: @Marti: No, it was [during the Reagan administration](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/2517/did-the-reagan-era-usda-really-classify-ketchup-as-a-vegetable).

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: thanks, didn't know that. Could've sworn it was in the news in the 90s - in the 80s I was too young to pay attention to such things.